# Where can I find up to date StructureMap documentation?

Tags: structuremap

http://docs.structuremap.net/ seems to have very old examples that use deprecated members.
Is there a place where I can find up to date StructureMap doco ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have found some of the newest documentation for version 3.1 at
http://structuremap.github.io/

It looks like it has most of the basic information is there. Some of the other pages don't seem to be fleshed out yet. But it still looks very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

There is no new development. Latest version on NuGet is 2.6.4. So all these examples are the best you can get right now.

We are using it for some years, and because principles are the same, it is (as a concept) still up to date...

Comment: I don't agree that it is up to date at all !!

Comment: What is not up to date? the documentation? the implementation? or the design? I would say, that Structure Map is working for us, no issues until now. So less code to configure, and powerful runtime features (including different profiles for different users or purposes) so what is not up to date?

Comment: Yes the question was in regards to the documentation.

Comment: For version 3.0.0.0 there are plans for better documentation. Structuremap is not dead: http://jeremydmiller.com/2013/01/30/lets-try-this-again-structuremap-3-0-in-en-route-as-of-now/

Comment: Latest docs for the v3.0.0 release are here: http://structuremap.github.io/structuremap/